# How do I get it to only return 1 row with the newest effective date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

[image: Sample 1]

This is a summarized version of the type of results I am getting and I would like to narrow it down to show only the rows where if the Payee and Tractor are the same, then only show the row with the code that has the newest "effective date". The effective date is when the Code was implemented. So I don't need it to show me someone's out of date code and I am not wanting to go in and delete their code history to eliminate them that way. I can't show my actual results as there is some sensitive customer information in the tables I'm working with.

*The effective date is not to be shown in the results but I inserted it there so that you could see it.

Currently my code looks like this... I'm not sure how to use the Max(Effective_Date) from the Seg_Alloc_Detail table to get it to do what I want. Seems like I would need some sort of nested condition in my select statement to get what I want, but I'm not sure how.

```
select distinct 
    Driver.Payee_ID as 'Payee Code',
    Payee.Name,
    Seg_Alloc_Code as 'Allocation Code',
    max(Effective_Date) as 'Effective Date', 
    Driver1_id as 'Assigned Driver',
    Tractor.ID as 'Tractor Number',
    Fleet_ID as 'Fleet', 
    Fuel_Card.Payee_ID as 'Card Payee',
    Fuel_Expense_ID as 'Expense Code'
from
    Driver
inner join
    Payee on Payee.ID = Driver.Payee_ID
inner join
    Seg_Alloc_Detail on Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code = Payee.ID
inner join
    Tractor on Tractor.Driver1_id = Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code
inner join
    Fuel_Card on Fuel_Card.Payee_ID = Tractor.Driver1_id

where Is_Active = 'Y' and Driver.Company_ID = 'TMS' and Seg_Alloc_Detail.Company_ID = 'TMS'

group by
    Tractor.ID,
    Driver.Payee_ID,
    Payee.Name,
    Seg_Alloc_Code,
    Driver1_id,
    Fleet_ID, 
    Fuel_Card.Payee_ID,
    Fuel_Expense_ID
```

Comment: Removed mysql tag as this seems to be sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `top 1 with ties` and `row_number()`:

```
select * 
from (
  select top 1 with ties
      Driver.Payee_ID as [Payee Code]
    , Payee.Name
    , Seg_Alloc_Code as [Allocation Code]
    , Effective_Date as [Effective Date]
    , Driver1_id as [Assigned Driver]
    , Tractor.ID as [Tractor Number]
    , Fleet_ID as [Fleet]
    , Fuel_Card.Payee_ID as [Card Payee]
    , Fuel_Expense_ID as [Expense Code]
  from Driver 
    inner join Payee
      on Payee.ID = Driver.Payee_ID 
    inner join Seg_Alloc_Detail
      on Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code = Payee.ID 
    inner join Tractor
      on Tractor.Driver1_id = Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code 
    inner join Fuel_Card
      on Fuel_Card.Payee_ID = Tractor.Driver1_id
  where Is_Active = 'Y' 
    and Driver.Company_ID = 'TMS' 
    and Seg_Alloc_Detail.Company_ID = 'TMS'
  order by row_number() over (
    partition by Payee.ID, Tractor.ID 
    order by Effective_Date desc
    )
  ) s
order by [Tractor Number]
```

Comment: This seems to work well, but messes with how I want the rows ordered. Is there a way to adjust this so that it is ordered by tractor number?

Comment: @JacobHyde Updated and moved ties query to a derived table, sort on the outer `order by`.

Comment: This is absolutely what I'm looking for. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: One question.. Why is the S necessary at the end of the closing ) before "order by [Tractor Number]"? What does that do?

Comment: @JacobHyde That is the alias of the derived table/subquery

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is sql server since you have a lot of sql server tags. You can leverage ROW_NUMBER for this type of thing. Here is one way to accomplish this.

```
select * --Really you would want to select only the columns from your subquery you want displayed instead of *
from
(
    select distinct 
        Driver.Payee_ID as 'Payee Code',
        Payee.Name,
        Seg_Alloc_Code as 'Allocation Code',
        max(Effective_Date) as 'Effective Date', 
        Driver1_id as 'Assigned Driver',
        Tractor.ID as 'Tractor Number',
        Fleet_ID as 'Fleet', 
        Fuel_Card.Payee_ID as 'Card Payee',
        Fuel_Expense_ID as 'Expense Code'
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Payee.Name, Tractor.ID order by Effective_Date desc) as RowNum
    from
        Driver
    inner join
        Payee on Payee.ID = Driver.Payee_ID
    inner join
        Seg_Alloc_Detail on Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code = Payee.ID
    inner join
        Tractor on Tractor.Driver1_id = Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code
    inner join
        Fuel_Card on Fuel_Card.Payee_ID = Tractor.Driver1_id

    where Is_Active = 'Y' and Driver.Company_ID = 'TMS' and Seg_Alloc_Detail.Company_ID = 'TMS'

    group by
        Tractor.ID,
        Driver.Payee_ID,
        Payee.Name,
        Seg_Alloc_Code,
        Driver1_id,
        Fleet_ID, 
        Fuel_Card.Payee_ID,
        Fuel_Expense_ID
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: This seemed to work after I added Effective_Date to the group by but I do not want rownum to show in the results.

Comment: Really you would want to select only the columns from your subquery you want displayed instead of *.

Comment: Sean Lange, your comment is spot on. You should update your answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number and get 1st value of desc effective date

```
;with cte as (
    select  
        Driver.Payee_ID as 'Payee Code',
        Payee.Name,
        Seg_Alloc_Code as 'Allocation Code',
        max(Effective_Date) as 'Effective Date', 
        Driver1_id as 'Assigned Driver',
        Tractor.ID as 'Tractor Number',
        Fleet_ID as 'Fleet', 
        Fuel_Card.Payee_ID as 'Card Payee',
        Fuel_Expense_ID as 'Expense Code'
    from
        Driver
    inner join
        Payee on Payee.ID = Driver.Payee_ID
    inner join
        Seg_Alloc_Detail on Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code = Payee.ID
    inner join
        Tractor on Tractor.Driver1_id = Seg_Alloc_Detail.EQ_Code
    inner join
        Fuel_Card on Fuel_Card.Payee_ID = Tractor.Driver1_id

    where Is_Active = 'Y' and Driver.Company_ID = 'TMS' and Seg_Alloc_Detail.Company_ID = 'TMS'

    group by
        Tractor.ID,
        Driver.Payee_ID,
        Payee.Name,
        Seg_Alloc_Code,
        Driver1_id,
        Fleet_ID, 
        Fuel_Card.Payee_ID,
        Fuel_Expense_ID
), CTE1 as
(
    select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by [Name], [Tractor Number] order by [Effective Date] desc) from CTE 
)
select * from CTE1 where RowN = 1
```